# Connect information from Azure AD to local Ad

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am building an application where users login via azure (oauth).
Now I want to find the logged in user in the local active directory, but how can I do that?

There is a promising objectId in the azure web admin ui but I can't find anywhere in my local AD.

I can't use the upn neither because the are not the same in azure as on my local ad.

There must be a way because the aad sync can keep track of changes as well.

This is the information the access token provides:

```
  {
 "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/3173e872-f73b-47d0-81c6-75e3ac726c21/",
 "iat": 1637937947,
 "nbf": 1637937947, 
 "exp": 1637943631,
  "acct": 0, 
 "acr": "1", 
 "acrs": [  
  "urn:user:registersecurityinfo"
  ],
  "aio": "ASQA2/8TAAAAha246r1Y5HNoFGcBvCtPqcvDnjil+dqoybNz9Gk57kk=", 
 "amr": [
   "pwd"
],
 "app_displayname": "myapp",
 "appid": "b958b44a-3b5c-14ac-b245-126b7524b35c",
 "appidacr": "0",
 "family_name": "Lustig",
"given_name": "Linda",
 "idtyp": "user",
 "ipaddr": "188.31.41.234",
 "name": "Linda Lustig",
 "oid": "9da1be1d-af4f-4d26-a9e7-e7e7a692471b",
  "onprem_sid": 
"S-1-5-21-4559353447-1638600113-3447510865-117118", 
 "platf": "8",
  "puid": "1003200160C8DCC6",
 "rh": "0.AXkAcuhzMTv30EeBxnXjrHJsIUu0iLlcXaxEs0dkayUks1x5AO0.",
 "scp": "openid profile email",
 "sub": "zpFbfmWNaR4YWYhWKHNEf3rVHVlavGX8DVQVQpPst_c",
"tenant_region_scope": "EU",
"tid": "3173e872-b76b-27d0-51c6-75e3ac726c21",
"unique_name": "lustig@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com",
  "upn": "lustig@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com",
  "uti": "nAcNGfeFek6iNmBwoJ9iAQ",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_st": {
    "sub": "3CEB7AUcrDeE6SKT1qde_FXWVeK9ppxZB576-PaIfwY"
  },

  "xms_tcdt": 1547151622
}
```

Comment: What about `sAMAccountName`, is it listed and does it match ? You can also use the Azure object id, it is mapped to the ldap attribute `msDS-aadObjectId`. @see [Attribute mapping for user accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/synchronization#attribute-mapping-for-user-accounts).

Comment: No the sAMAaccoutnNames are not always equal. I don't know why but I have some users where this is the case. I can't see an attribute msDS-aadObjectId neither with an ldap browser or the attribute-tab in ad-browser.

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT I am very sorry for the delay but because of management reasons I can't test your suggestion at the moment. I will test it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

•   Whenever the Azure AD Connect runs and starts synchronizing, it runs a check on every object in the Active Directory and tries to match the existing object in Azure AD as well. There are three attributes that are used for this process, viz., userPrincipalName(UPN), proxyAddresses and sourceAnchor. Thus, a match on userPrincipalName and proxyAddresses is known as a soft match and a match on sourceAnchor is known as hard match. Also, please note that for proxyAddresses attribute, the SMTP attribute in AD is considered as primary email address and used.

•   Thus, since as you said, UPN isn’t matching, you can try matching the other two attributes with on premises ones for finding the local users. Also, please note that sourceAnchor attribute is created when on premises AD attributes are first synced with Azure AD. After that, they remain the same for those identities synced and don’t change later unless changed externally. So, to locate the users based on sourceAnchor attribute, you can locate the equivalent attribute in Active Directory, i.e., ObjectGUID or ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid in on premises AD related to the identities that you are trying to locate.

Please refer the following link for more detailed information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-existing-tenant#sync-with-existing-users-in-azure-ad

Comment: I can't see an attribute with the name 'sourceAnchor' even after the user is synced to the cloud.

Comment: It is named as ObjectGUID in on premises AD/Azure AD Connect. Please try to find it there. Also, the ms-ds-consistencyguid attribute can also be checked for sourceAnchor in AD and then there corresponding proxyAddresses/UPN can be located in Azure AD. Also, you will be able to find sourceAnchor attribute in Azure AD Domain Services if you have it else you can't find it in Azure AD normally since it is a AD specific attribute.

Comment: I am a bit confused now can use the ObjectGUID from the cloud to find an entry via ldap? If so how va I do it?

Comment: The softmatch is something I haven't checked yet.

Comment: Check ObjectGUID in local AD for sourceAnchor attribute in Azure AD Domain Services. Also, check proxyAddresses/SMTP attribute for identities in AD that are synced in Azure AD.

Comment: Where do I find the sourceAnchor in azure, it not seams to be in the access token or the userInfo

Comment: Don't find sourceAnchor attribute in Azure AD, instead find ObjectGUID/ms-ds-consistencyguid attribute in local AD for the identities synced in Azure AD. Then, check their proxyaddresses/mail/smtp attributes in local AD and match them in Azure AD. Also, please check sourceAnchor in Azure AD connect configuration.

Comment: I found mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid but this doesn't seam to match the Object ID, but I don't know if I have to decode the obeject Id somehow.

Comment: ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid corresponds to sourceAnchor attribute in Azure AD Connect. Please check the same in Azure AD Connect for the identities synced in Azure AD. Also, check the corresponding mail/proxyaddresses attribute also, so that you can match the identities through them in Azure AD.

Comment: But I don't have the sourceAnchor in the oauth response.

Comment: How does the objectID that you stated in the question looks like?

Comment: Kind of like this 8de1ee0e-ef3f-4d26-e7a2-e7e7a692471b, It is the same as shown in the azure web ui.

Comment: Please note the corresponding object id's email/alias and compare them with the identities synced similar attributes from local AD in Azure AD Connect or in local AD attribute store.

Comment: I added the information I got from the access_token. This is everything I got to identify the user in the local ad.

Comment: I can see from the information that you added above that 'onprem_sid' is returned for the user object. Thus, you can use that 'onprem_sid' to retrieve details of the user object from local AD. Please run this command in elevated powershell on local AD DC, it will give the user details, i.e., DN of the user from AD: - [ADSI]"LDAP://<SID=S-1-5-21-500000003-1000000000-1000000003-1001>". Please replace the SID with actual SID received from the access_token.